# How do I add Same Solution Project References when exporting Templates in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, project-template, project-reference

I have a solution that contains several projects, lets call them ProjectA and ProjectB. I need ProjectA to have a reference to ProjectB, however when I "Export Template" I can't seem to keep the reference. What I am trying to do is to have it create the reference for me when I create a new project and then automatically name it to what I entered.

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly out of scope for pure Visual Studio templates.

Visual Studio templates supports replacements parameters for templates, so what you could do is:

- Inside your `ProjectA.zip` template file you will find `ProjectA.csproj`, which is the template for the project
- In `ProjectA.csproj` you will find an `<ItemGroup>` containing `<Reference>` entries
- Among them should be an entry like `<Reference Include="ProjectB">`

When you create a project from your ProjectB-template, it's name will be user-specified, so you want to replace `ProjectB` with a replacement parameter like `$Foo$`.

This is where it gets out of scope for pure templates: How do you tell visual studio to replace `$Foo$`? And what would the replacement be?

Your only choice here it to use a custom wizard, which either looks for the ProjectB-type project or asks the user for it.

Here's an outline for how to get the template and custom wizard to get along:

- Create a VSIX package project.
- Be sure to add the `[ProvideBindingPath]` attribute to your package. This is required to get the custom wizard registered (otherwise you would need to install it to the GAC, so VS can find it)
- Create your wizard, it should implement `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateWizard.IWizard`
- Add your template to the solution and add it as a ProjectTemplate asset in your package's vsixmanifest

In the .vstemplate file of your template, add the following snippet below the `<TemplateContent>` block:

```
<WizardExtension>
  <Assembly>Your.Packages.Assembly</Assembly>
  <FullClassName>Your.Wizard</FullClassName>
</WizardExtension>
```

That will bring up your wizard when the project is created. You could, in the `RunStarted` method bring up a dialog which asks for the reference or you could use the `automationObject` parameter (which actually is a `EnvDTE.DTE` instance) to try and find the ProjectB project and supply it's name in the `replacementsDictionary`.